# Germany blue card: contract start date changed

Tags: germany

I have a rather tricky problem: I’ve signed a contract which was supposed to start at April and the foreign office could only gave me an appointment at the last day of March. Since the company has an internal process for every employee before start, they asked me to provide the working permission not late than 10th March. I contacted the foreign office several times and was only told an early appointment is not possible.

Then I told the company, they postponed my start date to May. I just started the new job but feel now really bad because the contract I used to apply the blue card is the old one. Strictly speaking, the working permission was issued to that one (new contract only changed the start date nothing else). And I did some research it said a blue card normally is not assumed like one month before the start date (technically I’m one month unemployed when holding a blue card). Worse is my national pass only valid to next year, so is my blue card. Next year I have to renew it and that time the foreign office will find out that I didn’t start the job as the contract I gave them.

I’m quite worried now what should be done, should I talk to the foreign office ASAP? What could be the worst case (losing my blue card or even worse?) Anyone has had any similar situation? Thank you so much for help and suggestion!!

Comment: What did your company HR team say when you asked them?

Comment: Hi @Traveller thanks for the response. Before start, HR only said the deadline to hand in new working permission to them and if that could not be hold they could only postpone my start data. For a long time I haven’t realized it could be a problem to postpone the start data. I haven’t talked with HR now since I don’t know what should be done first (like explain to foreign office first?). Have you had any suggestion? Thanks a lot!